# Back transform from normal (Gaussian) data to actual data

Tags: r, gaussian, inverse-transform

I have converted raw data (a vector with some values) into normal (Gaussian) data, with mean = 0 and std = 1 with the following function:

```
nscores  <- qqnorm(RawVar)$x
```

Then, I wanted to convert the normal data back to Raw data. For that purpose, I have considered the backtr function as follow:

```
model <- data.frame(x = sort(RawVar), nscore = sort(nscores))
testbacktr <- backtr( nscores, model, tails = "none", draw = TRUE )
```

But, I do not get a reasonable answer. Is there any way to convert the data properly back to the actual units?

Comment: There‘s no way of tunring back a standard normal transformation into its original state. By definition, the standardization process turns any data into one with mean 0 and sd 1, which means that if you only have your transformed data, there‘s an infintie number of possible original data distributions. What you‘d need to turn back the process of the standardization is the mean and sd of the original distribution. Do you have this info?

Comment: @deschen you are right. I needed to use the raw data in order to do the back-transforming. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

a bit late, but here's my solution:

```
norm_trans <- function(x,x_backtr=NULL){
  #normal score transform data. mu=0, std=1:
  x_norm <- qqnorm(x)$x
  
  #backtransform data if the data to be backtransformed is available
  if (is.null(x_backtr)){
    return(x_norm)
  } else{
    return(approx(x_norm,x,x_backtr)$y)
  }
}
```

If only one vector with data is provided, then a (forward) normal score transfromation is performed.
If a second vector is provided, then this vector is backtransformed using the transformation that would have been performed on the first vector.

I hope this helps?